# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find' - plotting data in matplotlib with pandas

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I'm trying to split a `pandas DataFrame` into two and then plot the two halves, but I'm encountering an error when I try to plot.

The data I'm testing my code on is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xrvo3oy1s7hptl8/testdata).

It's a `DataFrame` with a row of titles, a row of units, and then data with a one row gap half-way down filled with `NaN` (just the way the data is stored).

I import the data with

`up = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=False, skipinitialspace=True)`

The first row with titles gets read as the column names.  It can't be plotted yet because of the row with the units in, so I remove the first row with `up2 = up[1:]`.

Now, I want to split the data where the row of `NaN` occurs, so I've defined a function `cutting` that returns the row where the `NaN` occur - `cut_loc = cutting(up2)`.

Now I apply the cut: `up3 = up2[:cut_loc-1]`, which should just shorten the `DataFrame`.  However, when I go to plot it `up3.plot(x='Field', y='Moment', color='red', label='Up'` I get the error `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'`

I can plot `up2`, but not `up` (because of the row of units) or `up3`.  I can't see why.  Anyone know?

Comment: can you add output of `up3.head( )` to your question?

Comment: `up3.head()` gives me the rows 1 to 5 of the data

Comment: Are you sure that data in your frames is numeric? When i wrote your file it was strings because of first(second) row

Comment: @AndreyShokhin I think that's the problem.  My data is of the form -130.9780E-06 (for example) and I can plot it when I convert it to floats, but I lose precision.  Although I don't think this explains why I can plot up2.