# Converting object to float loses too much precision - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to plot a `DataFrame` using `pandas` but it's not working (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612373/numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-find-plotting-data-in-matplotlib-wit) similar thread for details).  I think part of the problem might be that my `DataFrame` seems to be made of `objects`:

```
>>> df.dtypes
Field          object
Moment         object
Temperature    object
```

However, if I were to convert all the values to type `float`, I lose a lot of precision.  All the values in column Moment are of the form `-132.2036E-06` and converting to `float` with `df1 = df.astype(float)` changes it to `-0.000132`.

Anyone know how I can preserve the precision?

Comment: this is almost certainly just the printed precision. Do ``df.values`` after you astype will show the raw numpy values. You can also astype with ``np.float64`` if you are on 32-bit platform to make them 64-bit.

Comment: Different formatting doesn't mean your values have lost some digits. Compare df1 against float('-132.2036E-06').

Comment: @Jeff @Lorenzo Thanks guys, didn't realise the printed value would ever be different from the stored value.  `df.values` did indeed show no such loss of precision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this to change the displayed precision

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
          0         1
0  0.943371  0.171686
1  1.508525  0.005589
2 -0.764565  0.259490
3 -1.059662 -0.837602
4  0.561804 -0.592487

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [3]: pd.set_option('display.precision',12)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
               0              1
0  0.94337126946  0.17168604324
1  1.50852519105  0.00558907755
2 -0.76456509501  0.25948965731
3 -1.05966206139 -0.83760201886
4  0.56180449801 -0.59248656304

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff.  I've been struggling with this one all day.